# Variable Explorer in Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought, canopy

I'm new to python and have installed Enthought Canopy. Is there any way for viewing or exploring the variables like we do in MATLAB workspace inside Enthought Canopy? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is planned, but not available yet.

Comment: Yes, namespace browsing is now in internal testing, along with other debugger features. It is planned for release later this year.